# Write a method named isPrime, which takes an integer as an argument and returns true if the argument is a prime number

Tags: java

I think I have wrote the method correctly but when I try to input a number in the main method and run the script I get no output in console. Please help.

public class Q2_Prime {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    isPrime(19);
}
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
{
    if(number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You get no output because the code you wrote does not contain a single command to output anything. If you want to print something you'll need to write code for that, eG: `System.out.println(isPrime(19));` This might be a good read: [Differences between System.out.println() and return in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456472/differences-between-system-out-println-and-return-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You have to **print** the returned value to see it.

```
public class Q2_Prime {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    System.out.println(isPrime(19));
}
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
{
    if(number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
}
```

**BTW** you can use `for(int i = 2; i < number/2; i++)` which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

None of your code says anything should be written to the console. Change `isPrime(19);` to `System.out.println(isPrime(19));`