# Index X out of bounds for length X

Tags: java, string, loops, methods

I'm learning Java and while learning methods I came across an error. What's more, code does what I want, (it displays stars), but it also throws an error. I don't quite know why.

Here is code and error below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaskMethods {
    
    //Display the stars
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Insert number of stars:");

    //declare numbers of stars
        int num = getInt();

    //Display the stars by 'stars' method
        System.out.println(stars(num));
    }
    //method for input int variables
    public static int getInt(){
        return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    }

    //method for inputing stars to array and also for displaying them.
    public static String stars(int num){
        String[] star = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < star.length; i++){
            star[i] = "*";
            System.out.print(star[i]);
        }
        return star[num];
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cre8H.png)

I tried to limit the loop by the array lenght (like always) and It's nothing.
There is no line where we declare values ​​outside the range of the array.
In every post I've seen the problem was wrong range.

Thats why I'm looking for help here.

Comment: Arrays are indexed `[0...num)`, so `num` is out of bounds. Have a look again range of `i` in `stars` method, notice how it terminates at `i < stars.length`. Why do you return `star[num]` afterwards?

Comment: What is the point of `return star[num];`? Creating a local array and then only returning a single element makes little sense. That method should either return the whole array you created or return nothing at all and just print directly. I would also recommend reading [Differences between System.out.println() and return in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456472/differences-between-system-out-println-and-return-in-java)

Comment: When I was looking for an answer I saw this topic but I didn' found an answer. Now I see my mistakes (Thanks to all who comment). When I back home, I'll correct the code and paste it again.

Comment: @Adix what do you mean? Please **don't** edit your question to include fixed code. If you feel your question is not a duplicate then please paste revised code alongside some explanation in as an answer.

Comment: @orhtej2 sorry for misleading, I meant exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Without pre-allocation of the array, you can also  fill the stars using `String[] stars = Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(num).toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to access *star[num]*, which would be 1 outside the last indexed value.

```java
return star[num];
```

Additionally, you are supplying the return value of the *stars* method, to a *println* call, here.

```java
//Display the stars by 'stars' method
System.out.println(stars(num));
```

Which, isn't necessary, since *stars* uses *print* to display the value.

There are two approaches you can take.

One, simply call *stars(num)*, without the *println* call.
This would also allow you to remove the return type of *stars*—by changing it to *void*.

```java
//method for inputing stars to array and also for displaying them.
public static void stars(int num){
    String[] star = new String[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < star.length; i++){
        star[i] = "*";
        System.out.print(star[i]);
    }
}
```

Or, you can populate a *String* value within *stars*, and return that.

```java
public static String stars(int num){
    String[] star = new String[num];
    String string = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < star.length; i++){
        star[i] = "*";
        string += star[i];
    }
    return string;
}
```

Subsequently, you can reduce the *string* and *star[i]* assignment, within the *for-loop*.

```java
string += star[i] = "*";
```

And, since we're on the topic, you can utilize the *[Arrays#fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object))* method, to populate an array, and the *[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))* method to concatenate the values.

```java
public static String stars(int num){
    String[] star = new String[num];
    Arrays.fill(star, "*");
    return String.join("", star);
}
```

Furthermore, the *[String#repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))* method, can produce a sequence of repeating characters.

```java
public static String stars(int num){
    return "*".repeat(num);
}
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
Insert number of stars:
5
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your array is 3 of length. You will have stars at star[0], star[1], and star[2].
In the stars method, you return star[3] and this doesn't exist.